# При прокрутке страницы появляется второй скролл и не могу понять почему

Tags: html, css, slider, slick.js

https://roderen.github.io/onegin/
При прокрутке страницы появляется второй скролл и не могу понять почему...
Возможно из-за слик?

Comment: Вполне реально, что вы что-то намудрили со стилями, либо же неправильно настроили `slick` и он добавляет теперь свой -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо убрать `overflow-x`. Или просто заменить его на `none` вместо `hidden`

Вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS Это строчки 34-36 файла `style.css`

Answer (score 1):

У вас в файле style.css на 34 строчке написано overflow-x: hidden.

Уберите и скролл пропадает. При этом остальная работа сайта насколько я увидел не нарушается.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо вашего

```css
body, html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Напишите

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Прокрутки по оси x не будет, и второго скролла по y тоже не будет